# Are there alternate disk mounters running in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, fstab, smbclient

When I boot my Raspberry Pi it can't mount the Samba shares and it halts the booting process. Which is curios since those shares have the `nofail` option in the `fstab` file. But to get over this I've first commented out, then even deleted all the Samba shares in the fstab file. Still, every boot fails as it still tries to mount those shares.

The error message I get is:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /mnt/shared_drive.
See 'systemctl status mnt-shared_drive.mount' for details.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode.

Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue.
```

Hitting Enter does nothing, so I can't dig around in the running system.

Is there another service, which I've configured and forgot about that would try to mount Samba shares at boot time?

(Sidenote: The shares are up and mountable, I've tried the `fstab` settings in a virtual machine and it was able to mount the shares without issues.)

Comment: What's the error during boot?

Comment: @binarysta I've updated the question with the output I see on screen.

Comment: Well, boot process fails then system tries to launch root shell but root account is locked. You can mount the SD card to another computer and change the `/etc/shadow` for `root`, there is `*` or `!` for root just copy the one for `pi`. then root will have same password as pi user. then in boot process we can login the root shell and investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps created a systemd mount unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-shared_drive.mount`?

I guess it could exist in `/lib/systemd/system/` directory too, although you aren't supposed to make customizations there, as any package updates could overwrite them.

Also try updating your initramfs file with `update-initramfs -u`, just in case the old version of the `/etc/fstab` file stored in initramfs at the time it was last updated is causing the problem.